# Status of PostgreSQL replication after pause and resume

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup

To backup the PostgreSQL database we setup a slave server which uses streaming replication.

We found the commands `pg_xlog_replay_pause()` and `pg_xlog_replay_resume()`. So we thought we use the commands to pause the replication (the replaying of the xlogs), start `pg_dump` and then resume the replication.

How do I find out when the PostgreSQL database is again in sync after the "resume"? Usually I used this command to see the "lag":

```
SELECT extract(seconds from (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())) AS time_lag;
```

If I use it after `pg_xlog_replay_pause()` then it shows only a "lag" in seconds. So it seems that it is not the right query here. So is there a good solution for this?

One solution would be to write a cronjob on the master server to update a timestamp every minute and then check on the slave when the timestamp is more or less up to date. But I think there should be a better solution from PostgreSQL itself.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstood your question, `SELECT extract(epoch from (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())) AS time_lag;` should give you what you are looking for - the lag in seconds, not seconds portion of the lag as your original query returns.  You can achieve the same with a number of `extract (seconds ...) + extract(minutes ...)*60 + extract (hours ...) *60*24 +...`

Comment: The command always returns like 10s even if I called `pg_xlog_replay_pause()` before and waited one hour. So I cannot really see how "old" the state is of the slave.

Comment: @ChristophLSA I don't think you read the answer carefully enough.  The reason you get only the seconds part is because that is what `extract(seconds...)` does.  If you want the difference in seconds, not the seconds portion of the difference, then do `extract(epoch...)`, as the answer says.  It will work.